# Cant stub a method using OCMock

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I am using OCMock on an objC project.

I have the following code:

```
 DB_Account *Lena = [[DB_Account alloc] init];
    Lena.niceName = @"Lena";
    Lena.userId = @"Lena";
    id mockStorageManager = OCMClassMock([V4_StorageManager class]);

    [[[mockStorageManager stub] andReturn:Lena] getAccountByDBId:@1];

    id mockDBNotificationManager = OCMClassMock([DBNotificationManager class]);

    id partialV4DBNotificationManagerMock = OCMPartialMock([V4_DBNotificationManager manager]);

    [[[mockDBNotificationManager stub] andReturn:(NotificationPolicy *)[NotificationPolicy Never]] getNotificationPolicy];

    [[[partialV4DBNotificationManagerMock stub] andReturn:mockDBNotificationManager] dbNotificationManager];
    BOOL shouldShow = [[V4_DBNotificationManager manager] showOnLoginExpired:Lena];

    assertThatBool(shouldShow,is(isFalse()));
```

this code fails to compile on the following line:

```
[[[mockDBNotificationManager stub] andReturn:(NotificationPolicy *)[NotificationPolicy Never]] getNotificationPolicy];
```

with this error:

```
Error:(95, 5) multiple methods named 'getNotificationPolicy' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes
```

this method returns an object of type NotificationPolicy *, no other class implements or declares a method with this name.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to solve the problem

```
 [(DBNotificationManager*)[[mockDBNotificationManager stub] 
andReturn:[NotificationPolicy Never]] getNotificationPolicy];
```